# How can I order prints on clear plastic?

Tags: printing, prints, photolabs

I would like to get some photos printed on clear plastic.  I am picturing the equivalent of white photo paper, only clear, but I'm open to acetate like a transparency for an overhead projector, or a rigid plastic sheet or anything else that's clear.

In the past I've ordered photo prints from a variety of sources online from local camera chains to smugmug.com to retail chains.  I am not seeing the ability to print on clear plastic on any of them.

This question isn't about printing on clear plastic myself.  I've read about that, and I may end up pursuing that, but that's not what this question is about.

How can I order photos printed on clear plastic?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you want rigid plastic, ask the kind of shop that does signage and advertising materials for companies and trade shows, they can likely do it or arrange it done for you.

Answer (score 2):

If like for an overhead projector to project, I think the question is How can you find a shop that will print transparencies for you?   They are casually called slides, but the key word is Transparency.

I think most copy shops do that, call them and ask them.  Office Max, Office Depot, Staples, etc.

Or you can print them at home on your printer.  The media is called Transparency Film, available many places, Amazon, B&H or office supply stores.

See https://www.wikihow.com/Print-Transparencies

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.  I upvoted, but I think your answer can be improved by removing the paras about printing at home, because I specifically said this question isn't about that.  Thanks again!

Comment: The forum is not private, and the idea was that other readers might have questions too.  :)